What possible orders are there on terms, in the context of Knuth-Bendix completion?
I am studying Knuth-Bendix completion. Here is my current understanding.
Assume you have a finite set of equations on terms, $E = \{t_0 = t_1, t_2 = t_3, \ldots \}$.
Terms have the structure of trees.
I would like to what properties an order relation on terms must have in order for KBC to succeed and return a reduction system.
For example:

does it have to be a linear order?
can it be any linear order?

